# Set Default Value for Custom Field

Tags: custom-fields

I am trying to set custom fields in a Custom Group. Here is my code:

```
function dfi_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CustomData') {
    if ($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
      echo 'Hello World';
      $defaults['custom_160_-5'] = mt_rand();
      $defaults['custom_70_-5'] = '23/10/2019';
      $form->setDefaults($defaults);
    }
  }
}
```

I have added it as an extension. It is not working even the Hello World isn't showing.

Thanks

Comment: Try -1 instead of -5

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP - Thank you for trying to help me but unfortunately no, if i put -1 or even remove the _-5 or _-1 it still isn't working.

Comment: The formName probably isn't CustomData, it's usually something like CRM_XX_Form_XX. You can use a step-debugger or log it to the ConfigAndLog folder using CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message($formName).

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP - You were right, the formname was incorrect the issue now is after populating the form doesn't save the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moe's answer is technically workable - but oof ouch my performance!

Instead, something like this:

```
function getElementNameFromFieldName($fieldName, $elementIndex) {
  // This function could be further optimized so it's only called once, but meh.
  $elementNames = array_keys($elementIndex);
  foreach ($fieldNames as $fieldName) {
    if (strpos($elementName, $fieldName) === 0) {
      return $elementName;
    }
  }
}

if ( $formName == 'CRM_Contact_Form_CustomData' || $form == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
  $custom198ElementName = getElementNameFromFieldName('custom_198', $elementIndex);
  $custom197ElementName = getElementNameFromFieldName('custom_197', $elementIndex);
  $custom160ElementName = getElementNameFromFieldName('custom_160', $elementIndex);

  $form->updateElementAttr($custom198ElementName, ['readonly']);
  $form->updateElementAttr($custom197ElementName, ['readonly']);
  $form->updateElementAttr($custom160ElementName, ['readonly']);
}

if ($form == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
  $customid = rand (1,10000);
  $currentDate = date('d/m/Y');

  $defaults[$custom160ElementName] = $customid;
  $defaults[$custom197ElementName] = $currentDate;
  $defaults[$custom198ElementName] = $currentDate;
  $form->setDefaults($defaults);
}
```

Additionally -  your code (and mine) as written will set defaults on EVERY form's `ADD` action.  You probably want to limit it to those that have these custom fields.

Comment: Do i use the buildform hook or a different hook?

Comment: buildForm, yes.  The helper function goes outside the hook of course.

Comment: Thanks for your help but have got back these two error codes:

Notice: Object of class CRM_Activity_Form_ActivityLinks could not be converted to int in dfi_civicrm_buildForm() 
Error: Using $this when not in object context in getElementNameFromFieldName()

Comment: @Moe Sorry - I didn't test this code, it's intended more as a guideline than a copy-paste :)  However, I'll modify the code to handle the error.  The notice isn't being generated from this code (or even this hook)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of JaapJansma-CiviCooP

I was able to make this work using the below code:

```
function dfi_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
    if ( $formName == 'CRM_Contact_Form_CustomData' ) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++) {
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_198_'. $i,array('readonly'));
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_197_'. $i,array('readonly'));
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_160_'. $i,array('readonly'));
        }
     if ($form == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
        $customid = rand (1,10000);
        $currentDate = date('d/m/Y');
        for ($i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++) {
            $defaults['custom_160_-' . $i] = $customid;
            $defaults['custom_197_-' . $i] = $currentDate;
            $defaults['custom_198_-' . $i] = $currentDate;
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_198_-'. $i,array('readonly'));
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_197_-'. $i,array('readonly'));
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_160_-'. $i,array('readonly'));
        }
        $form->setDefaults($defaults);
       } 
    }
}
```

Thanks