# Default value for custom date field

Tags: custom-fields, dates

My CiviCRM 5.56.1 runs on Drupal 7.

I try to set the default value for a custom field which is used for an Action.

I created the field in Admin -> Customized Data & Screen -> Custom Fields. The field `custom_76_-1` is shown in the form, and it works, I can change the current value. This is a date field showing a year-value only, and I'd like to set it's default value from current year to 3 years before (eg. in this year from 2022 to 2019). On the UI I can set a fix date, not a relative date.

With Javascript / jQuery I can change the shown value of the year, but not the default value in the form. I tried to set the default value in the form with the code from this https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/33474/5877 answer, but it doesn't works for me -- I mean the default value didn't changed. As I understood, custom fields are created from an AJAX call's response, and the `buildForm()` function runs earlier as the AJAX call, which creates the custom field, so the default value can't be set (is this true or do / understand I something wrong?).

Please advice me how can I set the field's default value.

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_buildForm().
 *
 * @link http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm
 *
 */
function extensionname_civicrm_buildForm($formName, $form) {
  if ('CRM_Custom_Form_CustomDataByType' == $formName
    // type == cuctom group belongs to which type i.e Contact, Event, Activity...
    && in_array($form->getVar('_type'), ['Contact'])
  ) {
    foreach ($form->getVar('_groupTree') as $customGroup) {
      // custom group name in which the field you want to set default to.
      if ($customGroup['name'] == 'custom_group_name') {
        foreach ($customGroup['fields'] as $field) {
          // custom field name you want to set default to.
          if ($field['name'] == 'custom_field_name_type_date') {
            $defaults = [
              $field['element_name'] => date('Y', strtotime('-3 years', strtotime(date('Ymd'))))
            ];
            $form->setDefaults($defaults);
            break;
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both ```foreach``` are running, but no default value is set...

Comment: what type of custom field is it?

Comment: I created a custom group for Activities, in this group is a single field, which is a Date field, the format is "Year only" (%Y), no time is show, it's mandatory, searchable with range.

Comment: I have updated the answer